# Redirect a user after update

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a page that users will click a update link and once they land on the page it will tell the server to grab data from a API and takes a few minutes. The problem is I don't wan't to have to keep refreshing the page to send the user back once it has updated.

Is there a jQuery function that will check a PHP file every 10 seconds and if the PHP files says example yes it will the redirect them.

Sorry I'm new with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `GET`:

```
function detectChange(){
    $.get('file.php', function(data) {
      if(data == 'example'){
        document.location = 'http://example.com';
      }
    });
    setTimeout(function(){ detectChange(); }, 10000);
}

setTimeout(function(){ detectChange(); }, 10000);
```

Where the `10000` is 10 seconds in milliseconds. Check out [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more info.

Comment: I could get this one to work right away with no change except example.

Answer (score 2):

The set interval function lets you specify a function to run every x miliseconds. Param 1 is the function, param 2 is miliseconds.

You can use $.get, $.post, or $.ajax. Look up jquery docs or follow example below.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("phpFile.php",{[insert your params here]},function(serverResponse){
         if(serverResponse ==="yes")
              window.location = "redirect_file.php";
    }
},10000);
```

Comment: I understand the function you have. Now the question what should the php file output when yes? just text saying yes?

Comment: What are you doing with the PHP file? If its doing some serverside test, and you can make it say yes when you want to redirect, then it should just echo "yes";

Comment: I can make the php file say what ever when it's ready to redirect. So the php file just needs to say yes. Thank you.

Comment: in this case. if you want more rich info down the line, you might look into the php file outputting a JSON object. Just take a php array and pass it through the JSON encode php function. Then you can use the jquery $.getJSON, and you'll be able to do more interesting logic... but if its just yes or no, then this will work

Comment: This will check the file once after 10 seconds but only once, rather than checking _every_ 10 seconds.

Comment: @TomWalters how would I make it check every 10 seconds then?

Comment: I believe this is not the case... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: Set interval does this: "Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function."